# when i press a stop button in web view it should stop loading content

Tags: iphone, webview

i am using web view stop button to do this is working,but i want to write ibaction for this and when i press this it should stop loading content

how to stop web view to load...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW5):

> `stopLoading`
>
> Stops the loading of any web content managed by the receiver.

Comment: stop = [[UIButton alloc]   style:UIButtonTypeCustom target:self identifier:stop   action:@selector[webView stopLoading]];
 when i am using this is giving syntax eerror : is expected